Gemini AI API - Parallel batch file upload using python threads, fails
My current code is,

def upload_file(file_path):
    return genai.upload_file(pathlib.Path(file_path))


def analyze_frames(frame_paths):
    model = genai.GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-pro")
    prompt = """
Give me a description after looking at these images
"""

    # Upload the images using the File API
    logger.info("Uploading files...")
    file_references = []

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [
            executor.submit(upload_file, frame_path) for frame_path in frame_paths
        ]
        for future in tqdm(
            concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures),
            total=len(futures),
            desc="Uploading files",
        ):
            file_references.append(future.result())

    logger.info("Uploading files completed...")

    # Generate content using the file references
    logger.info("Making inferences using the model...", model.model_name)
    response = model.generate_content(
        [
            prompt,
            *file_references,
        ]
    )
    return response.text


def process_batches(frames, batch_size):
    # Split the frames into batches
    batch_list = [frames[i : i + batch_size] for i in range(0, len(frames), batch_size)]
    batch_results = []

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = {
            executor.submit(analyze_frames, batch): batch for batch in batch_list
        }

        for future in tqdm(
            as_completed(futures),
            total=len(futures),
            desc="Processing batches",
        ):
            batch_results.append(future.result())

    return batch_results

I call this as,
result = process_batches(frame_paths, 3550)
Problem
It uploads parallel correctly for sometime, and then hangs (doesn't progress after this)
Uploading files:   4%|████▍                  155/3550 [00:53<19:29,  2.90it/s]
Uploading files:   9%|████████▊              158/1850 [00:55<09:53,  2.85it/s]


Observations

It always fails around at ~160 images in each batch process

References

https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-python/issues/211#issuecomment-2143293996

https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-python/issues/327#issue-2285062757


